# Name for the Quotient $SU(m+1)/(SU(k) \times SU(m-k))$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, notation, definitions, homogeneous-spaces

The sphere $S^{2m-1} \simeq SU(m+1)/SU(m)$ has a canonical $U(1)$-action, and quotienting by this action give complex projective space $CP^m$. We can generalise the family of sphere to the family of spaces $S^{m,k}$ where we defines 
$$
S^{m,k} := SU(m+1)/(SU(k) \times SU(m-k)), ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ k = 1, \ldots, m - 1.
$$
It also have a $U(1)$-action, and quotienting by this give the Grassmanian $Gras(m,k)$.

**What is correct the name and notation for $S^{m,k}$?**

Comment: "The unit vectors in $\mathcal O_{Gr(m,k)}(-1)$", or wordlessly, perhaps $\mathcal O_{Gr(m,k)}(-1)_{||^2=1}$.

Comment: "Canonical circle bundle over the Grassmannian"?

Comment: "The unitary frame bundle of the tautological line bundle of the Grassmannian."